# How to move a folder(including subdirectories and files) into a new folder using Java code

Tags: java, directory, move

Can anyone help me for a Java code which copy or move one folder as it is into another folder.

For example:
I have a folder named `temp`, inside `temp` I have a folder `in-temp`.

I want that my `temp` folder should be copied or moved into a new folder named `new temp`, but by using Java code.

I got an example code by searching on Google which *copies* the sub-directories and files of a folder into a new folder, but as I said I need to *move* a folder with it's sub-folder into a new folder.

Help me to resolve this.

Thank you.

Comment: You might wish to start modifying the code you found via google, because the simple [`File.rename()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)) mechanism may or may not move hierarchies between filesystems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use apache-commons-io:

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(File, File)
```

Answer (score 0):

For most cases, specifically when source and target are on the same filesystem, respectively drive, the standard java.nio [`Files.move(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) command (available since Java 7) does exactly what you need. However, the command **will** fail in some cases, so you'd have to resort/fallback to to copy & delete the directory recursively (this pattern is also found in commons-io's [`FileUtils.moveDirectory`](https://github.com/apache/commons-io/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.java#L2375)).

This is a helper method that i just recently implemented in a Spring Boot project (as part of an effort to remove commons-io from the project's stack, using native & existing spring methods):

```
public static Path move(Path source, Path target) throws IOException {

    if (Files.exists(target)) {
        throw new FileAlreadyExistsException(String.format("Destination '%s' already exists", target));
    }

    try {
        return Files.move(source, target);
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
        // you may want some logging here, or just ignore the exception
    }

    FileSystemUtils.copyRecursively(source, target);
    FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(source);
    return target;
}
```

The two `FileSystemUtils` methods are part of the spring framework, but if you don't have a spring-based project… their implementations are pretty straightforward :)

I am documenting them here below, the following is just a copy from the original [source code from Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.3.x/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/FileSystemUtils.java#L79-L148).

```
/**
 * Recursively copy the contents of the {@code src} file/directory
 * to the {@code dest} file/directory.
 * @param src the source directory
 * @param dest the destination directory
 * @throws IOException in the case of I/O errors
 * @since 5.0
 */
public static void copyRecursively(Path src, Path dest) throws IOException {
    Assert.notNull(src, "Source Path must not be null");
    Assert.notNull(dest, "Destination Path must not be null");
    BasicFileAttributes srcAttr = Files.readAttributes(src, BasicFileAttributes.class);

    if (srcAttr.isDirectory()) {
        Files.walkFileTree(src, EnumSet.of(FOLLOW_LINKS), Integer.MAX_VALUE, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                Files.createDirectories(dest.resolve(src.relativize(dir)));
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                Files.copy(file, dest.resolve(src.relativize(file)), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    }
    else if (srcAttr.isRegularFile()) {
        Files.copy(src, dest);
    }
    else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Source File must denote a directory or file");
    }
}

/**
 * Delete the supplied {@link Path} &mdash; for directories,
 * recursively delete any nested directories or files as well.
 * @param root the root {@code Path} to delete
 * @return {@code true} if the {@code Path} existed and was deleted,
 * or {@code false} if it did not exist
 * @throws IOException in the case of I/O errors
 * @since 5.0
 */
public static boolean deleteRecursively(@Nullable Path root) throws IOException {
    if (root == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Files.exists(root)) {
        return false;
    }

    Files.walkFileTree(root, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            Files.delete(file);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
            Files.delete(dir);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

This code works great – if you're not sure what you're looking at here, then you'll want to develop a basic understanding of the [File Visitor API](https://www.baeldung.com/java-nio2-file-visitor) – which is a really powerful pattern to efficiently traverse directories for a multitude of purposes (i.e. get folder size, list files, etc.).